# How to solve this "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'."

Tags: java, android, github, android-gradle-plugin

When I try use issue from GitHub. I give in out

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'.

I try use Material Calendar View

> My gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mederov.timelord"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.5.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the later gradle versions `compile` was replaced with both `api` and `implementation`.

`api` exposes the dependencies to external modules, just like `compile`  does. So if you have module `A` depends on module `B` which depends on `C`, if `C` changes, then `A` needs to be recompiled. The Gradle team recognized this was unnecessary in a lot of cases, so it introduced `implementation` so if `C` changes only modules that depend on it will have to recompile, which means only module `B`. This shortens build times and makes the project much more tidy.

In short, if you replace all `compile` with `api` the result will be the same and that's what the warning is hitting at.

However, as a rule of thumb you'd want to use `implementation` whenever possible to avoid polluting the project with dependencies.

I'd try to first replace `compile` with `implementation` and build the project.

This [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) has a much better explanation and visualization of the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this line `compile 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.5.1'`

to this `implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.5.1'`